# How to get the logs of a POD in openshift to local file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, openshift

I have my spring boot application running on Openshift as container built using docker Image. I have enabled the logging in my application and prints all the logs. 
Now i want to examine the log files of the POD to check for any errors, since one my request is failing.  I do know about the command line option `oc logs -f <podname>`
That just prints the log into cmd prompt, but i want whole log to be copied from server to local file.
So that i can find some particular lines or errors. Is is possible?

Comment: Do you mean by jvm argument or doing it by a program?

Comment: Just by openshift from Browser or Openshift Commandline.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy files in and out of pods using the [rsync](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html) command.

Or use the `logs` command like you are and just redirect to a file so you can edit it locally:

```
oc logs  <podname> &> /path/to/file
```

Comment: But where will be the log file getting created in the POD i'm not sure.

Comment: @Lucia that depends on how you configure logging. If you're using a logging framework such as log4j or logback, then you can configure the logs to go to both stdout (so the container will get them) and a file of your choosing.

Comment: The tip with `oc rsync` is good. The problem I have is that rsync is not installed in the pod. :(

Comment: @ionescu77 What about `tar`? Looks like OC will fallback to creating a tar file and copy it out of the container if `rsync` is not present locally or in the pod: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/copy_files_to_container.html#copying-requirements

Answer (score 4):

### oc rsync

Try `oc rsync` as suggested above:

```
oc rsync <pod>:/path/to/file localfilename
```

However in my case I got:

```
WARNING: cannot use rsync: rsync not available in container <pod>
```

### oc cp

So I tried try `oc cp`, and it worked:

```
oc cp <namespace>/<pod>:/path/to/file local_filename
```

Without specifying the namespace the copy command will not work (and display no error message), so I had to which project the pod belongs.

#### Identify a pod's project/namespace

- `<pod>` is the pod name
- `<namespace>` is actually the project the `<pod>` belongs to.
- use `oc project` to list current project, or
- `oc projects` to list all projects
- or or search for the pod name in all projects `oc get pods --all-namespaces | egrep <pod>`

#### Important Note

```
 # !!!Important Note!!!
 # Requires that the 'tar' binary is present in your container
 # image.  If 'tar' is not present, 'kubectl cp' will fail.
```

```
 # about my environment
 # oc version
 # oc 3.6, openshift 3.7, kubernetes 1.7
```

#### Docs:

[OpenShift 4.3 Oficial Documentation - copying files](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-copying-files.html)

Answer (score 3):

From your oc CLI tool execute:

```
oc logs pod_name -n project_name > filename.log
```

Comment: This seems very similar to existing answers. Please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help. Particularily please point out how this is better than the other answers, or at least in which aspect it has an advantage.

Answer (score 2):

> That just prints the log into cmd prompt, but i want whole log to be copied from server to local file. So that i can find some particular lines or errors. Is is possible?

What about check `/var/log/containers` on the node which pods are running ?
There are all container logs which are symbolic links as `<pod name>_<namespace>_<container name>-<hash>` format. Basically, `oc logs` also refers the same container logs at there.

e.g.>

```
node ~# ls -1 /var/log/containers
alertmanager-main-0_openshift-monitoring_alertmanager-123...789.log
alertmanager-main-0_openshift-monitoring_alertmanager-456...123.log
alertmanager-main-0_openshift-monitoring_alertmanager-proxy-789...456.log
...
```

Answer (score 0):

login from oc cli tools, then switch to project, execute:

```
oc logs <podname> >> <podname>.log
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the file from fabric pod to your local machine

- To Connect to the fabric instance with oc login command

  oc login url--token=<token>>
- Check to connect pod using terminal

  oc rsh <podname>

  Just Check if it connects to POD and do some ls -lh(it should give some response)
- To Copy the file from remote POD to your local:

  oc rsync <podname>:<path>/logs.txt localfilename

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the oc login command.
2. Login into oc using login command on cli client.
3. Navigate to namespace where pod is hosted -> oc project project-name
4. Type in -> oc logs podname > pods_logs.txt

Log file is generated in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

oc logs pod_name -n project_name > filename.log

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

for me the way it works was to copy the folder with the logs  I was intended to get from my pod to the default path were the pod sent you when you login in the pod
and then apply:

```
oc cp <namespace>/<pod>:<myFolder> .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following command.

oc logs -f **podname** > **log-file-name**